# build.gradle structure for the following requirement in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Requirement,

1. I want to keep source code  inside first project.
2. I will have another second project where this project will  not have source code but will depend on first project and generate apk
   of second project.
3. I will have another third project where this project will  not have source code but will depend on first project and generate apk
   of third project.
4. any change done over in the source code should reflect in all the apks

Answer (score 0):

You can define a library in project1.

```
project1
  library1
    build.gradle
```

It is important to define the module as a library in `build.gradle` with

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

In project2 you can use the library1 defined in project1.

```
project2
  settings.gradle
  app2
    build.gradle
```

In `settings.gradle` you have to define:

```
include ':app',':module1'
project(':module1').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Project1/Module 1')
```

In `app2/build.gradle` you have to add the dependency:

```
dependencies{
  compile project(':module1')
}
```

You can do the same with the 3th project.

When you change the module1, you have to rebuild the project2/3.

Comment: as i  am working on a project where there are more than 5 apks of different client with different image,api but the source code remains same for all apks ,i wanted to config this using gradle ,using your above i am confused what to put in library1,module1.